# How to unmarshal a recursive json with type

Tags: go

I've got a JSON with the following form:

```
{
  "Filter": {
    "Filters": [
      {
        "Filter": {
           "someKey": "someValue1",
        },
        "FilterType": "trait"
      },
      {
        "Filter": {
           "someKey": "someValue2",
        },
        "FilterType": "trait"
      }
    ]
  },
  "FilterType": "and" // this can be an or too
}
```

Each filter has a type which maps to a particular struct I've got in code. As you can see this has a recursive nature: a filter can be `and` with multiple subfilters (which can also be `and`s or `or`s, etc).

So, depending on the type, I need to recursively map it to the correct struct. Any recommendations? I looked into using mapstructure but even then the code becomes pretty nasty.

Note, this example only uses `and` and `trait` filters but assume there are more like `or`

Comment: I think more of the feature specification is needed before I can provide an answer. 1. Does `"someKey": "someValue1"` imply that a filter can have more than one key/value pair? 2. Does `"Filters"` imply that a filter can have either an array of filters or a collection of key/value pairs? 3. How deep can this recursion go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This type of polymorphic JSON is common, and usually not easy to deal with. What I explain here is one way of doing it using a separate struct that is only used for marshaling, and relies on post-processing to construct the filters.

You can define a `FilterMarshal` struct that contains all possible fields of a filter:

```
type FilterMarshal struct {
   FilterType string `json:"FilterType"`
   Filters []*FilterMarshal `json:"Filters"`
   Filter   *FilterMarshal `json:"Filter"`
   SomeKey  string `json:"someKey"`
   ...
}
```

This implementation assumes that there are no name clashes. For instance, if a filter type has `Filter` field as one type, and another type has `Filter` field as an incompatible type, this will not work and you have to use other methods.

When you unmarshal the JSON in a `FilterMarshal`, you will get an object tree matching the input JSON. Then, you can construct the actual filter structure:

```
func unmarshalFilter(input *FilterMarshal) Filter {
   switch input.FilterType {
     case "and": 
        // process input.Filters recursively
       return AndFilter{Filters: processFilters(input.Filters))
     case "trait": 
       return TraitFilter{SomeKey: input.SomeKey}
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the absence of clarifying feature specifications this is the struct you need to represent something close to the JSON you posted in your question.

```
type FilterContainer struct {
    Filter     map[string]interface{} `json:"Filter,omitempty"`
    Filters    []FilterContainer `json:"Filters,omitempty"`
    FilterType string `json:"FilterType"`
}
```

Your filters would be initialized in Go like this

```
f := FilterContainer{
    Filters: []FilterContainer{
        {
            Filter:     map[string]interface{}{"someKey": "someValue1"},
            FilterType: "trait",
        },
        {
            Filter:     map[string]interface{}{"someKey": "someValue2"},
            FilterType: "trait",
        },
    },
    FilterType: "and",
}
```

When the filters get marshaled to JSON and pretty printed they look like this

```
{
  "Filters": [
    {
      "Filter": {
        "someKey": "someValue1"
      },
      "FilterType": "trait"
    },
    {
      "Filter": {
        "someKey": "someValue2"
      },
      "FilterType": "trait"
    }
  ],
  "FilterType": "and"
}
```

The above JSON doesn't exactly match the JSON in your question; it lacks the top-level `Filter` field. I think the struct I propose in this answer will simplify both the implementation as well as the mental model.

Give it a try in the Go Playground at https://go.dev/play/p/6cLPT28DG2O

**If you really, really need to match the JSON in your question**

here's the struct you'll need

```
type FilterContainer struct {
    Filter     interface{} `json:"Filter,omitempty"` // Either a map[string]interface{} or a FilterContainer
    Filters    []FilterContainer `json:"Filters,omitempty"`
    FilterType string `json:"FilterType,omitempty"`
}
```

and it is populated this way

```
f := FilterContainer{
    Filter: FilterContainer{
        Filters: []FilterContainer{
            {
                Filter:     map[string]interface{}{"someKey": "someValue1"},
                FilterType: "trait",
            },
            {
                Filter:     map[string]interface{}{"someKey": "someValue2"},
                FilterType: "trait",
            },
        },
    },
    FilterType: "and",
}
```

Try it out in Go Playground at https://go.dev/play/p/uB_LmJc6NGH